# Window title centered fluxbox

Tags: window, fluxbox

I'd like to center the window titles in fluxbox.
Now they are all at the right side.

How can I change this option?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all else fails, you can change the setting in the configuration file manually:

> window.justify in theme.cfg can be left, right. or center.

([source: Frank McCormick on the fluxbox-users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/fluxbox/mailman/message/30536716/))

System-wide themes live in `/usr/share/fluxbox/styles`, user-local themes live in `~/.fluxbox/styles/`.